# How to put excel window upfront in xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, pyautogui, visible, xlwings

How can I put excel window in front of other apps in terms of visibility? I am not interested in making it visible in `visible=True` attribute of App, because I can only see the excel window in taskbar. I need to see it in front of me (on top of other apps), so I can use pyautogui.

```
app = xw.App(add_book=False)
api_wb = app.books.api.Open(file_directory, UpdateLinks=False)
wb = xw.Book(impl=xw._xlwindows.Book(xl=api_wb))
```

A sample of the code is here. Although any other method of opening file will result in the same excel being wrapped to taskbar.
How can I solve this?

I also wanted to upload an image of the issue, but stackoverflow didn't let me saying: 'An error occurred when uploading the image: Service Unavailable'. The image format is .png

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the app and steal the focus like this:

```py
app.activate(steal_focus=True)
```

see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App.activate